# Property not initialized at super.init call using MVVM with convenience init

Tags: ios, swift

I have a **View Model** that subclasses `NSObject` as it is my `UICollectionViewDataSource`

I'd like to pass a service into this via dependancy injection.

I'm getting an error though

> Property 'self.chatService' not initialised at super.init call

```
class ChatQuestionsViewModel: NSObject {

    fileprivate var chatService: ChatService

    convenience init(chatService: ChatService = ChatService()) {
        self.init()
        self.chatService = chatService
    }

   private override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

And it appears to be focused on the `super.init()` line.

How can I initialise this class? I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a convenience initializer in this case. The rules of initializers state that you have to guarantee that all stored properties get initialized.

Convenience initializers are just that: for convenience only. This means it must not be *necessary* to use them to create an instance of the object. However if code uses your only non-convenience `init`, there's no initialization of `chatService`. (Never mind that your non-convenience `init` is private; that doesn't help).

Fixed result:

```
class ChatQuestionsViewModel: NSObject {
    fileprivate var chatService: ChatService

    init(chatService: ChatService = ChatService()) {
        self.chatService = chatService
        super.init()
    }
}
```